# Rails Bootstrap modal no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a Bootstrap modal to update the taskpriority field in the the tasks model.

This is the line in the modal that isn't working:

```
<%= simple_form_for :task, :url => url_for(:action => 'update', :controller => 'tasks'), :method => 'put' do |f| %>
```

The tasks controller has this code:

```
# PUT /tasks/1
# PUT /tasks/1.json
def update
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render json: @task }
    else
       format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The error I get is:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"tasks"}
```

Thanks !

PS - Is the an easier way to create a pop-up to change one field?

UPDATE 1

My rake routes for tasks

```
                 tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)                   tasks#index
                     POST   /tasks(.:format)                   tasks#create
            new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)               tasks#new
           edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)          tasks#edit
                task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)               tasks#show
                     PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)               tasks#update
                     DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)               tasks#destroy
```

Comment: try changing `:task` to `@task`

Comment: I get the same results using `@task`.

Comment: will you share your `rake routes`

Comment: I updated the questions with the rake routes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<%= simple_form_for @task, :url => tasks_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
```

Comment: I get `undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class`

Comment: i'm sorry then Reddirt, if that didn't work, i can't figure out what's happening here without a SSCCE

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the right answer.  But, sometimes when something doesn't work, you're better off trying a different approach.

I used x-editable instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `:task` or `@task` variable is not set. Try @sircapsalot's suggestion and show us the `tasks_controller#edit` action. Make sure that in there you are doing something like `@task = Task.find(params[:id])`.